# CPLEX 12.8.0 runtime error

Tags: cplex

I am trying to run the CPLEX java code on my macbook. I have installed CPLEX studio 12.8.0 version.

I have no problem compiling the code, however when I try to run the code it gives me following run time error.

**Error**

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at test.java.cplexTests.TestCplexExecutor.testCreateHiveModel(TestCplexExecutor.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
Native code library failed to load: ensure the appropriate library (opl1280.dll/.so) is in your path.
Exceptions:
no opl1280 in java.library.path
no oplb in java.library.path
no opl_lang_wrap_cpp in java.library.path
no opl_core_wrap_cpp_java1280 in java.library.path
no opl_core_wrap_cpp in java.library.path
no cp_oaas1280 in java.library.path
no cp_oaas in java.library.path
no cp_wrap_cpp_java1280 in java.library.path
no cp_wrap_cpp in java.library.path
no concert_wrap_cpp_java1280 in java.library.path
no concert_wrap_cpp in java.library.path
```

following is the command I using the run the code

```
mvn -Djava.library.path=/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/opl/bin/x86-64_osx  clean test
```

The only file with **opl1280** name exist is a mentioned below

> /Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/opl/bin/x86-64_osx/libopl1280.dylib

Answer (score 0):

finally found an issue, for some reason path provided using were ignored. Got that message when I ran maven in debug mode. `mvn -X`

added path in surefire plugin configuration and it resolved my issue.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.21.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <forkMode>once</forkMode>
        <argLine>-Djava.library.path=/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/opl/bin/x86-64_osx:/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/opl/oplide/</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```